# How should multiline pieces of code be put into a table?

Tags: tables, listings, verbatim, code

I have the following two pieces of information that I would like to present side-by-side in a Beamer slide. I think I'd like these two things in two cells of a two-column table. Is there a good way to do this? Is the verbatim environment a good idea for this? Would the listings environment be better?

```
SELECTION test1
JET_N 25000 >= 1
JET_N 25000 >= 2
JET_N 25000 >= 3
JET_N 25000 >= 4
#MV1_N 0.5 >= 1
#TEST test/test_test.config
#PRINT
SAVE

SELECTION test2
JET_N 25000 >= 1
JET_N 25000 >= 2
JET_N 25000 >= 3
JET_N 25000 >= 4
#MV1_N 0.5 >= 1
#TEST test/test_test.config
#PRINT
SAVE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`beamer` has the `columns` environment, makes sense to use that I think. Note that you need the `[fragile]` option to the `frame` in order to use `verbatim` and the like.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{columns}[t]
\column{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{verbatim}
SELECTION test1
JET_N 25000 >= 1
JET_N 25000 >= 2
JET_N 25000 >= 3
JET_N 25000 >= 4
#MV1_N 0.5 >= 1
#TEST test/test_test.config
#PRINT
SAVE
\end{verbatim}

\column{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{verbatim}
SELECTION test2
JET_N 25000 >= 1
JET_N 25000 >= 2
JET_N 25000 >= 3
JET_N 25000 >= 4
#MV1_N 0.5 >= 1
#TEST test/test_test.config
#PRINT
SAVE
\end{verbatim}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi @Torbjørn T. Thank you very much for your solution. It's clean and practically what I wanted.